# How can I invert every element of a list of a list of numpy floats in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of a list, where I want to do `1/x` for every element x.

I tried

`[1/x for x in list]`

How can I proceed? I tried multiplying as an example

`[x*10 for x in list]`

But this only increasing the number of rows by 10, and not multiplying the actual values. What am I doing wrong?

## Data

```
[[8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
 [8.049411010742187, 15.993977661132812, 24.147247314453125],
 [7.6774951171875, 15.250462036132813, 23.08390319824219],
 [7.450130615234375, 14.684713745117188, 22.35098876953125],
 [6.54051025390625, 12.876199340820312, 19.765568237304688],
 [5.39010986328125, 10.824963989257812, 16.51649169921875],
 [4.979031677246094, 9.665416870117188, 14.883976440429688],
 [4.6164859008789065, 8.65063751220703, 13.361966552734373],
 [3.9221954345703125, 7.188418579101563, 11.591380615234375],
 [3.4298834228515624, 6.534327087402344, 10.445729370117188],
 [2.9979116821289065, 5.92670654296875, 9.218810424804687],
 [2.7159127807617187, 5.452456359863281, 8.101337585449219],
 [2.216434326171875, 4.654409942626954, 6.799687652587892],
 [2.111146240234375, 4.231194915771484, 6.159953155517577],
 [1.6629426574707031, 3.4381407165527342, 5.140887298583984],
 [1.2951142883300781, 2.8314198303222655, 4.534166412353516],
 [1.1690933990478516, 2.3221934509277347, 3.6382754516601565],
 [1.1690933990478516, 2.1871324157714844, 3.230146026611328],
 [0.8830496215820313, 1.901088638305664, 2.645755157470703],
 [0.7231619262695312, 1.4308435058593751, 2.175510025024414],
 [0.2225925636291504, 0.7668316841125488, 1.5114982032775877],
 [0.2225925636291504, 0.4066648483276367, 0.9712825393676758],
 [0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504],
 [0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504],
 [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]]
```

Comment: Is this actually a list of lists? If so, why? A NumPy array would make this operation much more convenient and efficient.

Comment: It's actually an output from another list comprehension: `new = ([list(itertools.accumulate(x)) for x in old]) `

Comment: Right. I was thinking about this wrong and in terms of a list. It's a simple np operation if I convert it. Thanks!

Comment: [`numpy.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) could have handled the job you used the list comprehension for, too.

Comment: If `alist` is a lists of lists, then `x` in `[x for x in alist]` is itself a list.  `[1]*10` replicates the list; it doesn't multiply (in the numeric sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy` for pointwise arithmetic operations.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lst = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> a = np.array(lst, dtype=float)
>>> a
>>> 
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]])
>>> 1/a
>>> 
array([[1.        , 0.5       ],
       [0.33333333, 0.25      ]])
```

If you *must* use a list, use a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> [[1/x for x in sub] for sub in lst]
>>> [[1.0, 0.5], [0.3333333333333333, 0.25]]
```

... or in case you want an un-nested result:

```
>>> [1/x for sub in lst for x in sub]
>>> [1.0, 0.5, 0.3333333333333333, 0.25]
```

... and remember to not divide by zero. ;)

Answer (score 2):

As this question is tagged `numpy`, I thought I'd suggest a `numpy` function designed specifically for calculating `1/x`: [`numpy.reciprocal`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.reciprocal.html)

```
>>> a
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]])

>>> np.reciprocal(a)
array([[1.        , 0.5       ],
       [0.33333333, 0.25      ]])
```

Pretty simple, as stated in the docs:

> Calculates 1/x

But you should also note:

> Note:
>   This function is not designed to work with integers.
>
> For integer arguments with absolute value larger than 1 the result is always zero because of the way Python handles integer division. For integer zero the result is an overflow.

Comment: With a numpy array `a`, you can also just write `1/a`.  If you are using Python 2 and `a` might be an integer array, you can write `1.0/a` to ensure that the result is floating point.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `numpy` element-wise dividing.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.098671875, 16.09259521484375, 24.296372680664064],
     [8.049411010742187, 15.993977661132812, 24.147247314453125],
     [7.6774951171875, 15.250462036132813, 23.08390319824219],
     [7.450130615234375, 14.684713745117188, 22.35098876953125],
     [6.54051025390625, 12.876199340820312, 19.765568237304688],
     [5.39010986328125, 10.824963989257812, 16.51649169921875],
     [4.979031677246094, 9.665416870117188, 14.883976440429688],
     [4.6164859008789065, 8.65063751220703, 13.361966552734373],
     [3.9221954345703125, 7.188418579101563, 11.591380615234375],
     [3.4298834228515624, 6.534327087402344, 10.445729370117188],
     [2.9979116821289065, 5.92670654296875, 9.218810424804687],
     [2.7159127807617187, 5.452456359863281, 8.101337585449219],
     [2.216434326171875, 4.654409942626954, 6.799687652587892],
     [2.111146240234375, 4.231194915771484, 6.159953155517577],
     [1.6629426574707031, 3.4381407165527342, 5.140887298583984],
     [1.2951142883300781, 2.8314198303222655, 4.534166412353516],
     [1.1690933990478516, 2.3221934509277347, 3.6382754516601565],
     [1.1690933990478516, 2.1871324157714844, 3.230146026611328],
     [0.8830496215820313, 1.901088638305664, 2.645755157470703],
     [0.7231619262695312, 1.4308435058593751, 2.175510025024414],
     [0.2225925636291504, 0.7668316841125488, 1.5114982032775877],
     [0.2225925636291504, 0.4066648483276367, 0.9712825393676758],
     [0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504],
     [0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504, 0.2225925636291504],
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

a = 1/a

print(a)
```

**Output:**

```
[[0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12347704 0.06214038 0.04115841]
 [0.12423269 0.06252353 0.04141259]
 [0.13025082 0.06557178 0.04332023]
 [0.13422583 0.06809802 0.04474075]
 [0.15289327 0.07766267 0.05059303]
 [0.18552498 0.09237906 0.06054555]
 [0.20084227 0.10346165 0.06718635]
 [0.21661498 0.11559842 0.07483928]
 [0.25495925 0.13911266 0.086271  ]
 [0.2915551  0.15303795 0.0957329 ]
 [0.33356553 0.16872777 0.10847387]
 [0.36820034 0.18340358 0.12343641]
 [0.45117511 0.21485001 0.14706558]
 [0.47367633 0.23633986 0.1623389 ]
 [0.60134365 0.29085488 0.19451895]
 [0.77213263 0.3531797  0.22054771]
 [0.85536365 0.43062734 0.27485549]
 [0.85536365 0.45721969 0.30958353]
 [1.13243919 0.5260144  0.37796392]
 [1.38281616 0.69888845 0.45966233]
 [4.49251306 1.30406714 0.66159523]
 [4.49251306 2.45902739 1.02956654]
 [4.49251306 4.49251306 4.49251306]
 [4.49251306 4.49251306 4.49251306]
 [       inf        inf        inf]]
```